# Overwrite values in dataframe by using conditions from future values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a three column dataframe with columns: start_time, end_time, and value

I need to change the end_time when certain conditions are met.

```
    start_time  end_time  value
    1           1000      100
    10          1000      150
    50          1000      103
```

All end_time values start out the same, but I need to go through each number in the value column, starting with earliest start_time and find the next future value that is within 5%.  If there is a value within 5%, I want to replace the end_time with the start_time of the future value.  In the example above the table would now look like this:

```
    start_time  end_time  value
    1           50        100
    10          1000      150
    50          1000      103
```

This would continue through a longer list of values, always locating only the next future value that met the 5% condition and changing the end_time.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data.df)){
  # subset rows where value is within 0.05%
  start_times <- subset(data.df, abs(value - value[i]) < 0.05*value[i])
  # if any exist (excluding earlier events), edit end_time
  if(nrow(start_times) > 1){
    if(start_times$start_time[2] > data.df$start_time[i]){
      data.df$end_time[i] <- start_times$start_time[2]
    }
  }
}
```